# How to beat Duke Fishron?

Tags: terraria

I've been trying for a long time to beat Duke Fishron, but I always keep getting hurt badly and need to retreat.

What I've tried is using the weapons I got from the Moon Lord, flying around it and attacking, and shooting at it with weapons from the Arms Dealer.

I've tried Solar eruption, Vortex Beater, Stardust Dragon Staff, Nebula Arcanum, and the S.D.M.G

Any tips on how I could defeat him?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a tip, try putting [asphalt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Asphalt_Block) blocks over the ocean.  It seem to be the most common way to help best him.

Answer (score 0):

First for a start, You should get good wings to avoid a lot of the bosses moves.
You might have wings but idk because you didn't tell much. Also make sure you have good gear for the fight like fast boots and good armor.

Second, Build a platform on the ocean that's very long. This will give you more room to avoid and land on. In fact if you go on the land away from the ocean duke will start to go back and de-spawn

At last, If you don't have max hearts then get max hearts before fighting. This will help you out a lot in battle also take a lot of potions you might need you will need a lot of heath potions and greater ones too. Iron skin is a good choice to make sure the gear you has isn't bad also a pet might help as well.